# how to make the navigation options visible to only specific users

Tags: plugins, navigation-drawer, moodle

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRkdH.png).I have added attendance options in the navigation block, but i want it to be visible only for teachers

i have added lib.php code this way

```
function local_newattendance_extend_navigation(global_navigation $navigation)
 {
    global $CFG;
    if (!has_capability('local/newattendance:viewnewattendance', \context_system::instance())) {
        return;
    }
    $main_node = $navigation->add(get_string('pluginname', 'local_newattendance'), $CFG->attendance);
    $main_node->nodetype = 1;
    $main_node->collapse = false;
    $main_node->force_open = true;
    $main_node->isexpandable = false;
    $main_node->showinflatnavigation = true; 
}
```

this is access.php

```
    defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();


    $capabilities = array(
    'local/newattendance:viewnewattendance' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            //'manager' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            //'student'=>CAP_PREVENT,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        ),
    ),
);
```

this is local_newattendance.php in lang/en

```
 $string['pluginname'] = 'Attendance';
$string['newattendance:viewnewattendance'] = 'View local newattendance';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use capabilities for this eg:

```
function local_report_extend_navigation(global_navigation $navigation) {

    if (!has_capability('local/report:viewreport', context_system::instance()))) {
        return;
    }
```

To create the capability, add this to `/local/report/db/access.php`

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(

    'local/report:viewreport' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        ),
    ),

);
```

And add a string for the capability to `/local/report/lang/en/local_report.php`

```
$string['report:viewreport'] = 'View local report';
```

You will need to bump the version number in `/local/reports/version.php` for the capability to be installed

Comment: i made the changes exactly as mentioned, but i am still not able to achive as required. i have revised the post with recent changes, please have a look and suggest @RussellEngland

Comment: i have also bumped the version, and installed new capability, but still same @Russell